# Replace the opening ``` of double ``` pairs with ```bash

Tags: text-processing

I have a markdown file which contain code blocks as

In [310]: !cat data.md

````
**File Permission Related Commands**

These commands are used to change permissions of the files

```
72. chmod octal file-name                : Changes the permissions of file to octal
    chmod 777 /data/test.c                   : Sets rwx permission for owner , group and others
```

**Network Related Commands**

These commands are used to view and edit network configurations related aspects of the system

```
75. ifconfig -a        : Displays all network interface and set ip address
76. ifconfig eth0      : Displays eth0 ethernet port ip address and details
```

**Compression / Archive Related Commands**

These commands are used to compress and decompress files

```
89. tar cf home.tar  home         : Creates a tar named home.tar containing home/
    tar xf file.tar               : Extracts the files from file.tar
    tar czf  file.tar.gz  files   : Creates a tar with gzip compression
````

I'd like to replace the opening ```` ``` ```` (triple cavet)  with ```` ```bash ```` to mark the shell script which will be demonstrated in color by the editor.

I tried the answer.

````
In [327]: !sed 's/^(```)/(```bash)/g' data.md                                                                     
**File Permission Related Commands**

These commands are used to change permissions of the files

```
72. chmod octal file-name                : Changes the permissions of file to octal
    chmod 777 /data/test.c                   : Sets rwx permission for owner , group and others
````

but the opening ```` ``` ```` is not replaced.

How could I accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

The command ```` sed 's/^(```)/(```bash)/g' ```` doesn't work because round brackets are literally interpreted.
You probably have to escape the round brackets as in

````
$ sed 's/^\(```\)/```bash/g'
````

Alternatively, you can enable extended regular expressions:

````
$ sed -E  's/^(```)/```bash/g'
````

so that round brackets don't need to be escaped.

Or, just remove the round brackets:

````
$ echo '```' | sed 's/^```/```bash/g'
```bash
````

To match only the opening ```` ``` ```` you can use a regexp like this:

````
$ sed --null-data -E 's/[`]{3,3}([^`]*)([`]{3,3}){0,1}/```bash\1\2/g'
````

**Caveat**:  It fails if a ` (backtick) is found between sequences of triple backticks.

It uses `--null-data` to let `sed` treat the input as a single line (actually, lines separated by null charachters) and then looks for sequences of ```-text-``` to replace them with ```bash-text-```.

Comment: the solutions replaced both the opening and closing closing ```

Comment: Sorry, i got your question wrong. I updated my answer (and probably will update it again to make it better).

Answer (score 4):

To replace every other ```` ``` ```` line with ```` ```bash ````, it's probably easier with awk:

````
awk '$0 == "```" && alt = 1 - alt {$0 = "```bash"}; {print}' < file
````

To replace *every* ```` ``` ```` line, that would be:

````
sed 's/^```$/&bash/'
````

No need to explicitely capture the match (which by the way is done with `\(...\)`; `(...)` would only work after enabling extended regular expressions as supported by some `sed` implementations with `-E` or `-r`) when it's the whole match, as the whole match is captured as `&` anyway.

No need for a `g` flag. The `g` flag is to replace all occurrences *on the line*, but here, there can be only one occurrence per line as we're anchoring the pattern to the start and end of the line with `^` and `$`.

With `sed`, to replace *every other* line, you could do:

````
sed '
  /^```$/ {
    s//&bash/;:1
    n;//!b1
  }'
````

On one line:

````
sed -e '/^```$/ {s//&bash/;:1' -e 'n;//!b1' -e '}'
````

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can shorten it to:

````
sed '/^```$/{s//&bash/;:1;n;//!b1}'
````

(but that's not standard `sed` syntax as POSIXly, you can't have any code after the `:`, or `b` commands and there needs to be a `;` or newline before `}`).

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

````
 perl -ple 'if (m/^```$/) { if (--$|) { s/$/bash/ } }' data.md
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use single quotation mark for the `sed` command:

````
sed 's/^(```)/(```bash)/g'
````

This is used to avoid interpretation of the symbols from bash

But based on your file you better use something like:

````
sed 's/^```/```bash/g'
````

Comment: ty, I tried but ``` was not replaced.